# sources.list for jamvm

Tags: apt, java

Trying to install `jamvm` in my Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install jamvm
```

Unfortunately it can't find package `jamvm`

I suppose I must add something to `sources.list`. What I should place there? How to know sources list for desire application?

Comment: It was mistake, I'm using newest Ubuntu

Comment: If by jamvm, you mean [JamVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JamVM), it's been more than 7 years since it was last updated. I'm not sure if it is really installable at this point of time with all dependencies. Probably the Java version on which it relies is also *dead* by now.

Comment: There is not such version as newest that are at least 2 that can be called newest.